# How to get GPOINT by City in Google Maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have the string - "Moscow".

How to get a Gpoint (coords) from the my string?

I need result about : new GPoint(30.3112,59.99322);

Comment: What API version are you using?

Comment: @Yuri v2 can be deduced from the class name `GPoint` - v3 uses `google.maps.` namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, v2 API says that GPoint [does not represent](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPoint) a point on Earth by geographical coordinates but GLatLng does.

To get coordinates you need to use [geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GClientGeocoder):

```
geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng("Moscow", function(point)
{
    if (point == null)
    {
        // nothing found
    }
    else
    {
        // point is an instance of GLatLng with coordinates you need
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google Geocoding API will do the job for you, description and examples here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/